# Exchange 2003 Multi Server Administrative Group

Tags: email, exchange

I recently installed an additional Exchange 2003 server into my Exchange Organisation.  The server is in the same Administrative Group as the original server but mail flow doesn't seem to be working internally between them.  Eg. sending an email from a mailbox on the new 2003 server to a mailbox on the original 2003 server.

The email seems to be getting stuck in an SMTP Queue on the new 2003 server.  This queue I assume was auto created and has the name of the original server.  Eg. on the new server (BEXC2003) the queue is called AEXC2003.domain.local.  But AEXC2003 itself does not have a matching queue.  This queue always says 'Retry'.

I assumed that the mail flow within an Administrative Group would just work.  But that doesn't seem to be the case.  Any help would be appreciated.

For info, I also have an Exchange 2010 server which uses a Routing Group Connector to communicate with the 2003 servers, but I need to keep the 2003 servers because of their X400 connectors.

Many thanks,
Jason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All fixed now. A previous admin must have added some SMTP Connection Control IP addresses to restrict the email flow to certain servers. I added the additional Exchange server IP addresses to the list and the queue is now Active.